# How to fix -bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, terminal

Whenever I open up a new terminal I get the following:
`-bash: /Users/chrisjayden/.profile: No such file or directory`

I tried searching Q&A's but couldn't find anything relevant. 
+ I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: Can you show the the contents of `.profile` file, there could be some erroneous line causing this error

Comment: Most likely, you have either `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` that tries to source `~/.profile`, but `~/.profile` simply does not exist.

Comment: Could also be a corrupt `.profile` file, having a `.swp` extension

Comment: Neither the contents of the file nor any similarly named files are relevant. The error message is clear: something is trying to source or execute a file that simply does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

`-bash` indicates that your terminal is starting a login shell. That means `bash` will try to execute the contents of the first of the following three files that it finds.

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bash_login`
3. `~/.profile`

If all three were missing, `bash` would not complain. Therefore, we can assume that it finds one of the first two files, and in that file is a line like `source ~/.profile` or `. ~/.profile`, which *will* produce the error shown if `~/.profile` does not exist.

The easiest solution is to simply create an empty `.profile` file in your home directory.

Comment: I have a `.profile` but still don't have bash recognised ;(

Comment: When adding `. ~/.profile` to `.bash_logout`, `.bash_history`, `.bashrc` I get `$bash Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: It definitely doesn't belong in `.bash_history` or `.bash_logout`. I'm wondering if a seg fault could arise if`.bashrc` and `.profile` both source each other (creating an infinite loop).

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71111535/17840900)